# Биндинг к двум свойствам

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть сервер, у него есть кнопка Solve (решить задачу). Я хочу сделать так, чтобы ее свойство IsEnabled зависело от двух публичных свойств формы (которые я сам задал), но одно из свойств имело бы приоритет. Если IsRunning (сервер запущен) установлен в true, то Solve.IsEnabled == true и наоборот. (это свойство в приоритете) Но в тоже время если свойство Processing (задача в процессе решения) в true то Solve.IsEnabled == false (чтобы нельзя было запустить решение еще одной задачи, пока предыдущая не решилась) и наоборот. Я пытался сделать прямую зависимость от IsRunning биндингом, а обратную от Processing через триггер данных, но тогда биндинг берет на себя весь приоритет как бы и триггер уже ни на что не влияет. А если я пытаюсь обе зависимости триггерами задать, то влияет только последний заданный триггер.

```
<Button Content="Solve" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="9" Click="btSolve_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsRunning, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Processing, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Processing, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Можно добавить свойство `CanSolve`, логику которому вы уже описали в вопросе.

Comment: @Monk ага вот до этого я только что уже сам дошел.

Answer (score 2):

Единственный способ нашел сделать вот так:

```
public bool btSolveIsEnabled { get { return IsRunning && !Processing; } }
```

И прибиндиться в прямой зависимости.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что если это WPF, то теперь изменение свойств `IsRunning` и `Processing` должны оповещать и об изменении `btSolveIsEnabled`.

Comment: @Monk я знаю, но я использую для этого Fody.PropertyChanged, поэтому мне не надо об этом заморачиваться. :)